# How to react to default application answers

Tags: applications

I know that companies send out default rejections to save time. I applied for a one-month-internship and received a default positive answer, which was sent to me in the middle of the night (3.30 a.m.).

Even though I can work there (and finding an internship is really hard) I have some doubts. Maybe it is a good working place but it feels like they are not taking it serious or they are completely overwhelming me.

Is this a normal situation and am I overreacting?
How can I react to that?

Comment: I don't really see the problem - what's wrong with a default (/ template?) answer? Why would they bother writing the same, but slightly different, email from scratch for every candidate? That seems like a giant waste of time. What do you mean how can you react? React the same as you would if it weren't a template answer.

Comment: What was the "positive answer"?  Did they offer you the job or just an interview?

Comment: Call them and ask about the things that concern you.

Comment: @cdkMoose They offered me the job and even asked to sign the contract and send it per mail. I have never seen anyone of the company before.

Comment: Some middle/big size tend to do this is just to avoid wasting time and as @Dukeling the only difference between a template answer and a "normal" one is basically: "Hey!, great job! Now please come at our place and sign..."

Comment: So your only complaint is the time of day at which they sent the *positive* response?

Comment: Some HR person was working hard to get internship offers out. Do you want it or not?

Comment: You are way over-reacting. You don't have to decide to marry someone just because they agreed to go on a coffee date. Nor would you want to question their motiviations for agreeing - just go with the flow. Same is true in business. And jesus, you're only talking about a 1-mo. internship here. Get yourself out of analysis-paralysis and take the damn job.

Answer (score 4):

You are overreacting:

- what does it tell you that you received *a default positive answer*? HR or whoever answered you may have a ready to use template for such cases, but it doesn't mean they value you less.
- though you received the mail at 3.30 AM, it could have been sent by some office in a different time zone. Early morning for you, middle of the working day for them.

Unless you have sent an empty CV with an empty motivation letter and yet they hired you (which means they didn't bother reading your documents), I think their behavior is pretty normal. If you have questions about the company, just ask them and try to get a better idea on the company itself.